# Way to load data from Excel files along with files names to SQL Server using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, business-intelligence

I have number of similar format Excel files sitting in a folder and created SSIS packages for loading its data to a sql server table.

The data will be like :

```
EmpID, FirstName, LastName
```

These files have different names like Data01012020.xlsx, Data 02012020.xlsx

I would like to save these data to SQL Server using SSIS packages along with file name like:

```
EmpID, FirstName, LastName, ExcelFileName
```

I already holding the file name in a SSIS variable while looping through folder files. But showing truncation errors when try to push that to a DB field. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Foreach Loop Container`, set the Enumerator to `Foreach File Enumerator`, then configure it to your needs.

Withing the foreach loop, you can configure the Excel Source connection string to use a variable (or set it by an expression), later in the dataflow you can add the file name from the loop variable using a `derived column` component (index 0 in the variables section).

There is actually an article in BOL about this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/loop-through-excel-files-and-tables-by-using-a-foreach-loop-container?view=sql-server-ver15